# Evaluate queryset and then call filter on it

Tags: django

Is there a way to evaluate a queryset and then call filter on it? I want access database only once in this example

example:

```
qs = Model.objects.all()

for element in array:
  current = qs.filter(name=element)
```

Answer (score 2):

The call `qs.filter()` here generates a new queryset which has nothing to do w/ `qs`.
Also, according to [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated), `qs` and `current` keep un-evaluated until certain operations.

Comment: If you will perform some operations in forloop then you will have as many queries as elements in array. How to avoid this?

Comment: @szaman Ah, I see your point. There is no easy way to do that because one queryset is mapped to one sql directly.

Comment: @szaman  For ORM optimization, it depends on your usage, you could prefetch, cache, filter by Python, simplify the requirement, whatever..

Answer (score 1):

You can filter in Python:

```
qs = Model.objects.all()

for element in array:
    current = filter(lambda x: x.name==element, qs)
```

However, this is inefficient if your queryset and array are large. Alternatively, you can group your queryset by element:

```
from collections import defaultdict # 
qs = Model.objects.all()
grouped = defaultdict(list)
for obj in qs:
    grouped[obj.name].append(obj)

for element in array:
    current = grouped[element]
```

If `array` contains only a small subset of `name` values, it might make sense to limit the queryset:

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(name__in=array)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to build your query with one hit to the database, you are going to need to use a Q object:

```
from django.db.models import Q
q = Q()
for element in array:
    q &= Q(name=element)
qs = Model.objects.filter(q)
```